# Return to requested url after login

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, azure-ad-msal

I am making React App in which [msal-browser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/msal-browser) has been integrated for login.

**Steps to reproduce:**

-> Enter url in browser like `https://example.com/profile`

-> User is not logged in yet, so the user will be redirected to login page and upon clicking login button, user will be redirected to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/` .

-> Entered user credentials and once the login is successful, user was redirected to `https://example.com/home` post login.

**Expectation:**

-> But the user is expected to redirect back to the original/requested url which is `https://example.com/profile`.

**Things tried:**

I have tried configuring the auth like,

```
  auth: {
    clientId: clientId,
    authority: authority,
    redirectUri: redirectUri,
    navigateToLoginRequestUrl : true
  },
```

Thought `navigateToLoginRequestUrl` will do the trick but unfortunately it doesn't. Anyone here could able to help and get out of this blocker I am facing? Big thanks in advance.

Comment: Typically you would grab the current location *before* redirecting to the authentication flow so that your code can redirect *back* to the original location being accessed. I'm complete unfamiliar with this `msal-browser` though, and it's not clear how your code is using it and how the authentication flow is used. Can you edit your question to include a relevant [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @DrewReese, It will be like this one https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-cray-tmfsd9?file=/src/authConfig.ts . And the respective package I am using was https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/msal-browser .

Comment: @DrewReese, In the above example if we click on sign in and choose sign in using popup then it will redirect to https://login.windows-ppe.net/common and upon successful login user will be redirect to the redirect url. But only specific redirect urls will be configured in msal like `http://localhost:3000` , so if user enter the url manually **before login** like `http://localhost:3000/profile`, then it will redirect to login page and user will get logged in but after that it will be redirect to `http://localhost:3000` and not to `/profile` which is the issue.

Comment: Is `redirectUri` the URL to redirect to after successful login?

Comment: NM, the [source code](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-browser/src/config/Configuration.ts#L17-L29) says that `redirectUri` must "exactly match one of the redirect URIs registered in the Azure portal.". The `navigateToLoginRequestUrl` property does appear to be what you want to use. What isn't working with that set to true?

Comment: @DrewReese, Yes I have used `navigateToLoginRequestUrl: true` , but it doesn't redirect back to the requested url instead it redirect to the redirect url which is something like, `http://localhost:3000` .

Comment: Yes `redirectUri` is the url gets redirect after successful login.